# How to read in a .txt file when the column names are inline with the data with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

I'm trying to read in a .txt file into a  dataframe using Pandas. The problem I'm getting is that the column names are in line with the data for each row. This makes it a little hard for me to get only the data since I'm not sure what the delimiter should be. My data looks like this: (full file [here](http://militzer.berkeley.edu/FPEOS/files/Al_EOS_09-18-20.txt))

```
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    2020958 P[GPa]=       1877.100    24.300 E[Ha]=       -59.56300000  1.39000000

f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    4041916 P[GPa]=       4249.300    18.400 E[Ha]=       160.64900000  1.07400000

f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    8083831 P[GPa]=       9208.000    31.500 E[Ha]=       513.26500000  1.80900000
```

What I've tried doing is:

```
Al = pd.read_csv('Al_EOS_09-18-20.txt', skiprows=18, delimiter='=', names=['f', 'N', 'rho[g/cc]', 'V[A^3]', 'T[K]', 'P[GPa]', 'E[Ha]'])
```

What this returns is a dataframe with the correct columns, but the values under each column contain the value and the name of the next column. So under Al['f'] I get 'Al N' instead of just 'Al'.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: It seems like a lot of people are using `read_csv` for things that have nothing to do with CSVs.  It would take you about 15 minutes to write a script to convert this file into a standard CSV format that pandas would be happy to accept,.

Comment: @TimRoberts People use the tools they are comfortable with. Saying "it would take...15 minutes to...convert this [to a CSV]" is loading with assumptions that I don't think are safe to make. The OP clearly recognized something off, and is asking how to do it better.

Answer (score 3):

#### `pd.read_fwf`

Fixed Width

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url = "http://militzer.berkeley.edu/FPEOS/files/Al_EOS_09-18-20.txt"
s = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')

df = pd.read_fwf(
    io.StringIO(s), skiprows=18, header=None,
    usecols=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15],
    names='f N rho[g/cc] V[A^3] T[K] P[GPa]0 P[GPa]1 E[Ha]0 E[Ha]1'.split()
)

df

      f  N  rho[g/cc]      V[A^3]       T[K]    P[GPa]0  P[GPa]1     E[Ha]0  E[Ha]1
0    Al  1   0.269861  166.025618    2020958     1877.1     24.3    -59.563   1.390
1    Al  1   0.269861  166.025618    4041916     4249.3     18.4    160.649   1.074
2    Al  1   0.269861  166.025618    8083831     9208.0     31.5    513.265   1.809
3    Al  1   0.269861  166.025618   16167663    18629.3     36.3   1055.213   2.077
4    Al  1   0.269861  166.025618   32335325    37424.5     33.7   2129.898   1.924
..   .. ..        ...         ...        ...        ...      ...        ...     ...
235  Al  1   2.383356    1.383547   16167663  2126283.1   5177.3    938.925   2.532
236  Al  1   2.383356    1.383547   32335325  4411441.4   4979.6   2046.679   2.373
237  Al  1   2.383356    1.383547   64670651  8944752.2   4660.1   4212.630   2.231
238  Al  1   2.383356    1.383547  129341301  7991672.2   4802.6   8525.231   2.314
239  Al  1   2.383356    1.383547  215568835    17138.4   7894.0  14252.907   8.470

[240 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: That's really helpful! Just out of curiosity, why does this way require p[GPa] and E[Ha] to be split up into 2 columns? Is it something to do with pd.read_fwf or the way the file was read into s?

Comment: You can actually do more with `read_fwf` to specify the columns more precisely.  By default, it just identified where the white space was and what made sense.

Comment: In each row, there are two values for those columns. Pandas objects work best with scalars and numeric datatypes. To include those elements as a list or tuple in single column would severely limit what you can do with those columns

Comment: Thank you @PaulH.  I should've pointed that out as well.

Comment: Thankyou both for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the names of you columns you in theory also know your separators. You can do some regex.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]= 0.269861 V[A^3]= 166.02561792 T[K]= 2020958 P[GPa]= 1877.100 24.300 E[Ha]= -59.56300000 1.39000000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]= 0.269861 V[A^3]= 166.02561792 T[K]= 4041916 P[GPa]= 4249.300 18.400 E[Ha]= 160.64900000 1.07400000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]= 0.269861 V[A^3]= 166.02561792 T[K]= 8083831 P[GPa]= 9208.000 31.500 E[Ha]= 513.26500000 1.80900000"""


sep = 'f= |N= |rho\[g/cc]= |V\[A\^3]= |T\[K]= |P\[GPa]= |E\[Ha]= '

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=sep, 
                 names=['f', 'N', 'rho[g/cc]', 'V[A^3]', 'T[K]', 'P[GPa]', 'E[Ha]'],
                 engine='python').reset_index(drop=True)


     f  N  rho[g/cc]      V[A^3]     T[K]            P[GPa]  \
0  Al   1   0.269861  166.025618  2020958  1877.100 24.300    
1  Al   1   0.269861  166.025618  4041916  4249.300 18.400    
2  Al   1   0.269861  166.025618  8083831  9208.000 31.500    

                     E[Ha]  
0  -59.56300000 1.39000000  
1  160.64900000 1.07400000  
2  513.26500000 1.80900000
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I haven't used regex before so I was struggling a little bit trying to solve this without them haha.

Comment: @Crusher101 in regex, `|` means "or" and \ is used to escape a special character like `[` or `^` which mean something else in regex.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to create dummys that will store the unwanted values and then drop them when you are done extracting the data:

```
names = [1, 'f', 2, 'N', 3, 'rho[g/cc]', 4, 'V[A^3]', 5, 'T[K]', 6, 'P[GPa]0', 'P[GPa]1', 7, 'E[Ha]0', 'E[Ha]1']
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',
                 sep='\s+',
                 index_col=False,
                 names=names)
df.drop(range(1, 8), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

df

```
    f  N  rho[g/cc]      V[A^3]     T[K]  P[GPa]0  P[GPa]1   E[Ha]0  E[Ha]1
0  Al  1   0.269861  166.025618  2020958   1877.1     24.3  -59.563   1.390
1  Al  1   0.269861  166.025618  4041916   4249.3     18.4  160.649   1.074
2  Al  1   0.269861  166.025618  8083831   9208.0     31.5  513.265   1.809
```

Comment: Omg that's so simple, can't believe I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: Happy to hear :)
By the way, your implementation assumes that by setting the delimiter you're automatically setting the column and value of your data. 
The case really is that delimiter is an alias to 'sep' which just splits your line in a similar way that str.split() does and sets the values of the given names accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pandas I would have used a regex and then constructed a dataframe

```
import re

text = '''f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    2020958 P[GPa]=       1877.100    24.300 E[Ha]=       -59.56300000  1.39000000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    4041916 P[GPa]=       4249.300    18.400 E[Ha]=       160.64900000  1.07400000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=    8083831 P[GPa]=       9208.000    31.500 E[Ha]=       513.26500000  1.80900000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=   16167663 P[GPa]=      18629.300    36.300 E[Ha]=      1055.21300000  2.07700000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=   32335325 P[GPa]=      37424.500    33.700 E[Ha]=      2129.89800000  1.92400000
f= Al N= 1 rho[g/cc]=   0.269861 V[A^3]=     166.02561792 T[K]=   64670651 P[GPa]=      75127.600    29.100 E[Ha]=      4284.24400000  1.66400000
'''

m = re.findall('f=\s*(.+?)\s*N=\s*(.+?)\s*rho\[g\/cc\]=\s*(.+?)\s*V\[A\^3\]=\s*(.+?)\s*T\[K\]=\s*(.+?)\s*P\[GPa\]=\s*(.+?)\s*E\[Ha\]=\s*(.*)', text)


df6 = pd.DataFrame()

df6[['f','N','rho[g/cc]', 'V[A^3]','T[K]', 'P[GPa]','E[Ha]']] = pd.DataFrame(m)
df6
```

If you don't know about regex, they are pretty easy to learn and you can test them on sites such as https://regex101.com/. In any case, I will explain the one that I used.

\s*  says zero or more occurrence of whitespace characters
.+? requires at least one character
() are used to extract the regex.

Keep in mind that you could have searched for a specific type of character. For example, if you need one or more digits use d+, where d stands for digit and + means one or more.

Hope I could help, even if the answer is a little bit different from the logic you were using.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm not very familiar with regex so walking me through your code was very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom parser and generate a list of dictionaries to pass to the dataframe constructor.

***NOTE:*** this leaves the columns with 2 floats as strings.  You'd have to parse them separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url = "http://militzer.berkeley.edu/FPEOS/files/Al_EOS_09-18-20.txt"
s = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf-8')

def parse_line(line):
    line = [x.strip() for x in line.split('=')]
    line[0] = (None, line[0])
    line[-1] = (line[-1], None)
    line[1:-1] = [x.rsplit(maxsplit=1) for x in line[1:-1]]
    (_, *values), (*keys, _) = zip(*line)
    return dict(zip(keys, values))

df = pd.DataFrame(map(parse_line, s.splitlines()[18:]))

df

      f  N  rho[g/cc]        V[A^3]       T[K]                  P[GPa]                       E[Ha]
0    Al  1   0.269861  166.02561792    2020958      1877.100    24.300    -59.56300000  1.39000000
1    Al  1   0.269861  166.02561792    4041916      4249.300    18.400    160.64900000  1.07400000
2    Al  1   0.269861  166.02561792    8083831      9208.000    31.500    513.26500000  1.80900000
3    Al  1   0.269861  166.02561792   16167663     18629.300    36.300   1055.21300000  2.07700000
4    Al  1   0.269861  166.02561792   32335325     37424.500    33.700   2129.89800000  1.92400000
..   .. ..        ...           ...        ...                     ...                         ...
249  Al  1  32.383356    1.38354684   16167663   2126283.100  5177.300    938.92500000  2.53200000
250  Al  1  32.383356    1.38354684   32335325   4411441.400  4979.600   2046.67900000  2.37300000
251  Al  1  32.383356    1.38354684   64670651   8944752.200  4660.100   4212.63000000  2.23100000
252  Al  1  32.383356    1.38354684  129341301  17991672.200  4802.600   8525.23100000  2.31400000
253  Al  1  32.383356    1.38354684  215568835  30017138.400 17894.000  14252.90700000  8.47000000

[254 rows x 7 columns]
```